# ionic 2 hide item based on navparams

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I want to hide/show a list item on page load based on navparams, I have this code:

HTML

```
<button ion-item  (tap)="goToPage2()" [hidden]="shouldHide">Page 2</button>
```

TS

```
export class Page1 {
  public firstParam:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, params: NavParams) {
  this.firstParam = params.get("firstPassed");
}
```

What do I need to add to hide/show the button based on the firstParam params?

Thank you

Comment: need some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<button ion-item  (tap)="goToPage2()" *ngIf="shouldHide">Page 2</button>
```

Ts

```
export class Page1 {
  public firstParam:any;
  public shouldHide:boolean;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, params: NavParams) {
  this.shouldHide = false;
  this.firstParam = params.get("firstPassed");
  if(params.get("firstPassed") == "??"){
     this.shouldHide = true;
  }
}
```

This would show your Page2 button if the params you get passed are equal to the String of '??'. But because we miss some context to this question, I'm not sure whether or not you're looking for this.